# Git rebase multiple merges/branches

Tags: git, rebase

I have a scenario where I have made a branch off master, lets call it A, made some changes. Then had to branch off A, let call it B, and made some more changes. I then merged B into A, so now A has both the commits from A and B.

I now need to rebase branch A onto master and squash the commit from branch B, but when I do this I lose all the changes that were on branch B and only the changes from branch A are there.

I am wondering how do I rebase onto master squash the commits and still have all the changes?

Comment: How do you rebase ? and how do you squash your commit ?
I recommend to to rebase, check. If it is good squash with `git rebase -i`

Comment: Why do you think that you lose any changes? I think you won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to squash the commits from B, then:

1. rebase B onto A first
2. squash B so now it is a single (or similar) commit on top of A
3. rebase A onto master